# Countif inside if VBA

Tags: vba

What I want to do is count how many times the tags have been used in each type and write them into a different sheet. My data are as follow.

[image: Sample data]

For this example, it would be like this:

```
         A  B   C   D   F   H   K   L   M   N
Type1    1  1   1   2   1   1
Type2    1  1   1           1   1   2   1   1
```

Code:

```
Sub Countif_trial()

Dim myString As String
Dim xRange As Range

Set xRange = Range("C2:C8")

myString = Range("A2").Value

If InStr(myString, Type1) Then

Range("h1").Value = Application.CountIf(xRange, "A")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Please post it as well as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: If you are planning to receive output such as `A -1, B -1, C -1, D -2, F -1, H -1 ` in a cell then a User Defined Function would likely be the best bet. Have you got anything to show so far?

Comment: @RichardErickson: I added the code. But there I'm giving the cell range as C2:C8. If I give the range as C2:C17, I get the wrong count (it counts the tags that have been used in both Type1 and Type2)

Comment: @Jeeped: No, I do not want to get the output as that. I want to get it in another sheet with Tags in one column and corresponding counts in the next column

Comment: Did my edit to your sample results get a little closer to the truth?

Comment: Thank you for editing your example to include code.

Comment: @RichardErickson: :)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem are the blanks in column A where the *Type* is only implied by the last entry and not defined for each row. If the *Type* column was fully populated, this would be a simple [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

[image: COUNTIFS using last known]

Put the following into a module sheet.

```
Function udf_Count_Tag_by_Type(ByVal rTAGs As Range, sTAG As String, _
                               ByVal rTYPs As Range, sTYP As String)
    Set rTYPs = Intersect(rTYPs, rTYPs.Parent.UsedRange)
    Set rTYPs = Application.Range(Application.Index(rTYPs, Application.Match(sTYP, rTYPs, 0)), _
                                  rTYPs(rTYPs.Cells.Count))
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Chr(42), rTYPs.Offset(1, 0), 0)) Then
        Set rTYPs = rTYPs.Resize(Application.Match(Chr(42), rTYPs.Offset(1, 0), 0), 1)
    End If
    Set rTAGs = rTYPs.Offset(0, rTAGs.Column - rTYPs.Column)
    
    udf_Count_Tag_by_Type = Application.CountIf(rTAGs, sTAG)
    
End Function
```

> syntax:
>      =udf_Count_Tag_by_Type(*<type_range>, <type>, <tag_range>, <tag>*)

In the sample image in F5 as,

```
=udf_Count_Tag_by_Type(Sheet5!$C:$C, F$4, Sheet5!$A:$A, $E5)
```

Fill both right and down.

Here are two array¹ formulas that can populate G4:O4 and E5:E6.

```
'in G4 then  CSE and fill right
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet5!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet5!$C:$C, MATCH("zzz", Sheet5!$C:$C )), MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E4:E4, Sheet5!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet5!$C:$C, MATCH("zzz", Sheet5!$C:$C ))), 0)), "")
'in E5 then  CSE and fill down
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet5!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A, MATCH("zzz", Sheet5!$A:$A )), MATCH(0, IF(LEN(Sheet5!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A, MATCH("zzz", Sheet5!$A:$A))), COUNTIF(E$4:E4, Sheet5!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A, MATCH("zzz", Sheet5!$A:$A))), 1), 0)), "")
```

After they have been entered correctly, fill right and down for a few rows/column more than is immediately necessary in order to automatically catch new entries as they appear in Sheet5!C:C.

This UDF is likely a little more complicated tha it needs to be. A [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) probably would have been more than adequate. However, I've been trying to write all UDFs in such a way that they can receive full column references for more universality without suffering calculation lag.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: When I run this on module sheet, a Macro window pops up. All I did was, Alt+ F11, added a module to the sheet, copy-pasted this, select all and F5. Am I doing it right? I am a newbie to VBA, so sorry for bothering. And one more thing, you said it would be easy to do if column A is filled with types. If so, how can this be achieved? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's actually intended to be used on a worksheet just like any other function. See the sample image and the yellow **Syntax** blockquote for usage.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! :). I would like to learn how this code works. Are there any references I should refer?